# d3 sorting of an array of objects

Tags: sorting, d3.js

How do I update a vertical bar chart in d3 after having sorted the array of objects holding my data?

My (surely petty) problem is best seen here : http://jsfiddle.net/yJq3e/3/

After the bars creation, I call the `sortBars()` function, which works fine (as `console.log` can tell me) until I update the y-attribute. I assume it's connected to the y-attribute being actually dependent on the index (or the key?). However, I would've thought calling

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.name); })
```

on the `.bar`-attribute again after sorting should suffice as it does when I set the attribute for the initial position of the bars.

any help much appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would do in D3 is to sort the underlying data and pass that to `.data()` again. Like so:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
   .data(dataset.sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; }))
```

The rest of the code can remain unchanged. I've added a transition to make it look nicer. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yJq3e/5/).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense ! It doesn't seem to order it descendingly though. Using `d3.descending` doesn't change this. Again, `console.log` shows the correct order but the bars end up in a different, yet still unordered way. Any ideas top of mind?

Comment: The problem is that the `y` position is determined by the name, which doesn't change. You could determined it based on the index of the data point -- http://jsfiddle.net/yJq3e/10/

Comment: I'd vote your answer up if I had any reputation. Will be back when I've grown up ... much obliged !

Comment: I'm not sure this is ok to bug you again, but - after a break - I'm back in the sorting-struggle...

Comment: My first question would be : can you explain the use of the line `function (d) {return d.name;}` after the comparator function ? In what capacity is `d.name` used? Secondly, I added an ascending, descending and undo sort functionality like so : http://jsfiddle.net/yJq3e/16/ (surely there are more elegant ways with less code). All work fine, but after I hit the _undo sort_ button d3 doesn't order the values but the array-index, although all sort functions clearly work on `d.value`. Can you help me understand? Apologies for the pester - my little brain is breaking ..

Comment: The `function(d) ..` is the key function that tells D3 how to match data, in this case by `name` (so if two `name`s are the same, the data items are considered equal). Your undo function doesn't work properly because the dataset array is modified in place by `.sort()`, so you have to re-sort -- http://jsfiddle.net/yJq3e/17/